# Hosting webservice in IIS 7.0 (Not WCF)

Tags: c#, web-services, iis-7

I have written a webservice in C# and am trying to host it on IIS 7.0. Consider the following code, this code works fine and can be hosted on IIS 7.0 with no problems:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using VMware;

namespace vmareService
{
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Service1
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the     following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]

    public void logintoVmware(string URL, string username, string password)
          {
        VMware.Vim.VimClient client = new VMware.Vim.VimClient();

    }

}
}
```

Now if I want this method to return my session id, I change my code to following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using VMware;

namespace vmareService
{
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Service1
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the     following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]

    //public void logintoVmware(string URL, string username, string password)
    public VMware.Vim.UserSession logintoVmware(string URL, string username, string password)
    {
        VMware.Vim.VimClient client = new VMware.Vim.VimClient();
        VMware.Vim.UserSession session;
        session = client.Login(URL, username, password);
        return session;

    }

}
}
```

Now while I have referenced the vmware.vim.dll in my code and have also included the file in my folder hosted on IIS 7.0 ,, i get the following error message:

```
Server Error in '/vmService' Application.

Could not load file or assembly 'VMware.Vim, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=10980b081e887e9f' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file  specified.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'VMware.Vim, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=10980b081e887e9f' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'VMware.Vim, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=10980b081e887e9f' could not be loaded.


WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value    [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Stack Trace: 


[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'VMware.Vim, Version=5.0.0.0,      Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=10980b081e887e9f' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
System.Signature._GetSignature(SignatureStruct& signature, Void* pCorSig, Int32 cCorSig, IntPtr fieldHandle, IntPtr methodHandle, IntPtr declaringTypeHandle) +0
 System.Signature..ctor(RuntimeMethodHandle methodHandle, RuntimeTypeHandle declaringTypeHandle) +236
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.get_Signature() +91
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.get_ReturnType() +19
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.ToString() +36
System.Web.Services.WebMethodReflector.GetMethods(Type type) +255
System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescriptionReflector.Reflect(Type type, String  url) +77
System.Web.Services.Protocols.DocumentationServerType..ctor(Type type, String uri) +203
System.Web.Services.Protocols.DocumentationServerProtocol.Initialize() +388
System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocol.SetContext(Type type, HttpContext context,  HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) +75
System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing) +143

[InvalidOperationException: Unable to handle request.]
System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext  context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing) +458971
System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.CoreGetHandler(Type type,   HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) +285

[InvalidOperationException: Failed to handle request.]
System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.CoreGetHandler(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) +401754
System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String verb, String url, String filePath) +281
System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String url, String pathTranslated) +89
 System.Web.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute () +425
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&  completedSynchronously) +263

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5456; ASP.NET      Version:2.0.50727.5456
```

any help would be appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: You should make sure this file is in your /bin folder. If it is, then you should investigate what its potential dependencies may be. Remember, just because this file is there doesn't mean all of its dependent dlls are available.

Comment: Hi Joel, God knows how many times this forum has saved my life. You are a genius and I really want to thank you for this.

Comment: Did that solve your problem? If it did, I'll post it as a viable answer.

Comment: One more thing that is happening,,, Now I am able to host the service on IIS but when trying to use that webservice i get errors. I have tested the webservice by hosting it via VS2010 and running another instance of VS2010 to invoke. it works fine when in VS but when hosted on IIS it starts asking for dlls and assemblies it otherwise wouldnt ask for... is there any difference between VS2010 hosting and IIS hosting?

Comment: hi Joel, Yes that did solve my problem. Now I can host it no problem. but invoking the method exposed by it on IIS is not working. What should I do to make it work? Why am I able to invoke the method in VS2010 but not in IIS 7

Answer (score 0):

Pasted from Comment:

You should make sure this file is in your /bin folder. If it is, then you should investigate what its potential dependencies may be. Remember, just because this file is there doesn't mean all of its dependent dlls are available.

Comment: All Done all good, the issue was with a missing assembly in c:\windir\assembly

Comment: comments like this would be more helpful to other readers if you stated which assembly was missing..